# PHP re-format Blogger Date

Tags: php, xml

I found the date format in XML file is quite different than its showing on the page. 
Here is an example, 
http://google.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

The formate of XML is 
`<published>2011-04-01T08:06:00.000-07:00</published>`

How to re format **2011-04-01T08:06:00.000-07:00** to **Saturday, 2 April 2011 4:13 a.m.**

Many thanks for any advices and help :-)

Comment: The date format is given in [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), a very standard computer-to-computer representation.  The Date class will easily parse that and then you can format it however you wish.

Comment: Looks like a standard format that PHP's date functions would recognize, in which case simply employ [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date()`](http://php.net/date).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks guys!
Have got it done.

```
 $date=strtotime("2011-04-01T08:06:00.000-07:00");
 $date = date('l,F jS Y  g:ia', $date);
```